# Xaf Radio button / Message box / Dialog Box

Tags: user-interface, devexpress, popupwindow, xaf

Is there any way to show a radio button in the UI using Xpress App Framework? I have been using enums for providing options to select either of two values and then using datasource criteria/properties on them. Also I would like to know if we can populate messagebox / dialogbox at the user end with WebApplications?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Avoid asking two separate questions in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard XAF control for radio buttons, but there is [a Knowledge Base article](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E444) demonstrating how to create your own custom editor.

For your question about messagebox functionality, I refer you to these discussions:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q365097
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S33494
https://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/103663.aspx

(The first place to ask any DevExpress-related questions is their [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)).